Off-topic posts and suggesting an alternative
Regarding cdecker's comment at https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13413/how-to-change-uri-handler-from-bitcoin-qt-to-electrum#comment17221_13413 
I don't mean to aim any criticism at cdecker, just throwing you under the bus as an example of something I wish would become standard practice. My thinking is when adding an off-topic comment, I think it would be very helpful to make it etiquette  to suggest and link an alternative stack site if one exists. 
Thoughts? I know this cant be enforced in anyway but perhaps added to some guideline list.  At least until we can migrate more easily.  Speaking of which (going meta-meta now) this very topic might belong more in stackexchange meta or something. 

Unfortunately, the question seems to have been removed, so I can't see what you are refering to. However, I think it would be nice to cut down off-topic questions as quickly as possible (as they are more likely to only be helpful to individuals), but to add a suggestion where to go for help when close-voting.

@Murch Hmm, looks like something similar is already possible.  See answer

OK, looks like there's already a good way to do this -- but not on a beta site!

Flag the question
Select "It should Be closed for another Reason"
Select "Off Topic"
Select "It belongs on another Stack Exchange Site"

Then it gives you a choice of a few alternatives which seems to be automated based on keywords in the question or something.

Can you give an example of a recent question on bitcoin.SE where you can do this? As far as I know, the migration paths that you're referring to are only available for graduated sites (and they're the same for all questions on that site. It's not based on keywords), but not for beta sites. Beta sites only include a migration path to that site's meta.

@JohnBensin Oh, I think you're right. Didn't realize that.

Right, so in this case, it's probably better just to flag it for moderator attention and use the Other box to give a custom description of where you think the question belongs and why.
